# Play videos in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013 I want to have a web part with 3 videos. When the user click on one of them,
the player will open in a new window. Videos must be streamed in order to preserve bandwidth.

I started learning about the media web part, but I'm still pretty new to SharePoint 2013 so I don't want to spend time on a solution that doesn't work in the end.

If you have any ideas on what solution would best fit my scenario, that would help me greatly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone.

The player from Sharepoint 2013 supports only certain formats(for HTML5 : asf, avi, mpg, mp3, mp4, ogg, ogv, webm, wma, wmv ; classic Silverlight Media Web Part supports: asf, mp3, mp4, wma, wmv).

I had to support swf files so I searched for other options. I found this one https://code.google.com/p/youplayer/downloads/detail?name=mediaplayer.swf and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have limited experience with video libraries in SharePoint 2013, but here is what has worked for me:

Quicktime formats open in a new window.
WMV format will play in the browser.

I have had a lot of problems with just uploading mp4 files (never finishes the upload, regardless of file size), and haven't tried out the others.